# Oracle8 ULN 'dnf check-update' differs from 'dnf update'

Tags: perl, dnf

I recently migrated a RedHat 8 system to Oracle Linux ULN and I'm seeing a discrepancy between "dnf update" and "dnf check-update" (see output below). The listed Perl modules are installed but the .noarch version which I would prefer to retain. Is there a reason why "dnf check-update" would show these modules?

```
#dnf update
This system is receiving updates from Unbreakable Linux Network or Spacewalk.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:36 ago on Mon 17 Aug 2020 12:27:08 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

#dnf check-update
This system is receiving updates from Unbreakable Linux Network or Spacewalk.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:54 ago on Mon 17 Aug 2020 12:27:08 PM EDT.

perl-Algorithm-Diff.src         
perl-Archive-Tar.src            
perl-CPAN-Meta.src              
perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements.src 
perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML.src         
perl-Data-OptList.src           
perl-Digest.src                 
perl-Env.src                    
perl-Exporter.src               
perl-ExtUtils-Manifest.src      
perl-File-Fetch.src             
perl-File-Temp.src              
perl-HTTP-Tiny.src              
perl-IO-Socket-IP.src           
perl-IPC-System-Simple.src      
perl-Locale-Maketext.src        
perl-MRO-Compat.src             
perl-Math-BigRat.src            
perl-Module-Build.src           
perl-Module-Load.src            
perl-Module-Load-Conditional.src
perl-Module-Metadata.src        
perl-Package-Generator.src      
perl-Params-Check.src           
perl-Perl-OSType.src            
perl-PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint.src 
perl-Pod-Checker.src            
perl-Pod-Escapes.src            
perl-Pod-Parser.src             
perl-Pod-Perldoc.src            
perl-Pod-Simple.src             
perl-Pod-Usage.src              
perl-Sub-Exporter.src           
perl-Sub-Install.src            
perl-Term-ANSIColor.src         
perl-Term-Cap.src               
perl-Test-Harness.src           
perl-Text-Balanced.src          
perl-Text-Glob.src              
perl-Text-ParseWords.src        
perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap.src         
perl-Thread-Queue.src           
perl-Time-Local.src             
perl-autodie.src                
perl-bignum.src                 
perl-constant.src               
perl-experimental.src           
perl-inc-latest.src             
perl-libnet.src                 
perl-parent.src                 
perl-perlfaq.src
```

Comment: One comment I failed to mention - this is reproducible across multiple systems migrated from EL8 to ULN, so I don't believe it's an issue with a single system. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this url https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_faq.html#why-are-dnf-check-update-packages-not-marked-for-upgrade-in-the-following-dnf-upgrade

Comment: Thank you - I checked that document before but I'm still seeing the Perl packages as update candidates. No combination of dnf and update/upgrade or --best --allowerasing flags allows me to try and update those packages. Even if I attempt to reinstall the individual packages, I'm presented with the .noarch module and check-update again displays the same modules.

Comment: As per this link https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/16/modular-perl-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8/ can you please check two different version on perl available (installed) on the system

Comment: All my servers are running the default Perl installation (5.26.3). The other available version is 5.24 which is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing for a clean install of Oracle Linux 8 (public repos).

I have tried the same things as suggested. I didn't try and disable the older module yet with dnf module disable.

Looking at the modules I get:

## dnf module list perl

Last metadata expiration check: 1:40:34 ago on Sat 22 Aug 2020 07:00:51 PM PDT.
Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream (x86_64)
Name           Stream                Profiles                     Summary
perl           5.24                  common [d], minimal          Practical Extraction and Report Language
perl           5.26 [d][e]           common [d], minimal          Practical Extraction and Report Language

Trying to disable the 5.24 stream causes a pile of issues like:

## dnf module disable perl:5.24

Last metadata expiration check: 1:42:40 ago on Sat 22 Aug 2020 07:00:51 PM PDT.
Only module name is required. Ignoring unneeded information in argument: 'perl:5.24'
Error: Problems in request:
Modular dependency problems:

Problem 1: module freeradius:3.0:8020020191122172113:fbe42456-0.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed

- conflicting requests
- module perl:5.26:820181219174508:9edba152-0.x86_64 is disabled
  Problem 2: module freeradius:3.0:8010020190614154208:fbe42456-0.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
- module perl:5.26:820181219174508:9edba152-0.x86_64 is disabled
  Problem 3: module freeradius:3.0:8000020190425181943:75ec4169-0.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
- module perl:5.26:820181219174508:9edba152-0.x86_64 is disabled
  ...

I hope that helps figure out the issue.  Either that or I just do a -xperl-* when doing a dnf list updates.

Comment: Well I'm glad I'm not alone! I tried something similar to exclude Perl, but then I worried I would miss legitimate updates. Worked around it piping dnf to regex: `grep -v 'perl-.*\.src'`